# IE fails to load CSS file

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, request

I have problem with site: http://ggmedia.pl/ - IE fails to load http://ggmedia.pl/style.css

When I look on HTTP headers there isn't any request for this file. Changing filename and/or path doesn't help - any ideas?

Comment: +1 I can confirm it on IE8 & Windows 7. The headers look o.k, this is really mysterious.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the `<meta name="description" ...` tag, the `content` attribute has 2 quotes in it ("). Remove those or escape them (`&quot;`) and it should be fine.